# Cognito respond to challenge always gives 'Invalid session for the user.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have setup a custom authentication flow with cognito to enable email MFA. I am using the java sdk to make the api calls to log a user in with cognito.

My initiate auth works fine and my create challenge sends a verifcation code to the users email address.

However, when i am using the respondToAuthChallengeRequest to respond to the first challenge which is the custom challenge i get the error **NotAuthorizedException: Invalid session for the user**.

I am carrying over the session from the initiateAuthRequest so am i unsure what is going wrong here?

This is my code to begin the authentication process

```
       try {
           AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client = getAWSCognitoIdentityClient();

           String username = "testuser";
           String password = "password1";

           final Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
           authParams.put("USERNAME", username);
           authParams.put("PASSWORD", password);
           authParams.put("CHALLENGE_NAME", "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE");

           final AdminInitiateAuthRequest initiateAuthRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                   .withClientId("my client id")
                   .withUserPoolId("my user pool")
                   .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH)
                   .withAuthParameters(authParams);

           final AdminInitiateAuthResult result = client.adminInitiateAuth(initiateAuthRequest);

           String mfaCode = getUserInput();

           authenticateMFA(result, mfaCode);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

```
public static void authenticateMFA(AdminInitiateAuthResult challenge, String mfaCode) throws Exception {

    AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client = getAWSCognitoIdentityClient();
    Map<String, String> challengeResponses = new HashMap<String, String>();

    challengeResponses.put("USERNAME", "testuser");
    challengeResponses.put("ANSWER", mfaCode);

    System.out.println(challenge.getSession());

    RespondToAuthChallengeRequest respondToAuthChallengeRequest = new RespondToAuthChallengeRequest();
    respondToAuthChallengeRequest.setSession(challenge.getSession());
    respondToAuthChallengeRequest.setChallengeName(challenge.getChallengeName());
    respondToAuthChallengeRequest.setClientId("my client id");
    respondToAuthChallengeRequest.setChallengeResponses(challengeResponses);

    //user logged in using email MFA
    RespondToAuthChallengeResult respondToAuthChallengeResult = client.respondToAuthChallenge(respondToAuthChallengeRequest);

    System.out.println(respondToAuthChallengeResult);
}
```

Define challenge

```
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
   if (event.request.session && event.request.session.length === 0) {
       event.response.issueTokens = false;
       event.response.failAuthentication = false;
       event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
       
   } else if (event.request.session && event.request.session.length === 1 && event.request.session[0].challengeName === 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' && event.request.session[0].challengeResult === true) {
       event.response.issueTokens = true;
       event.response.failAuthentication = false;
   } else {
       //user did not provide a correct answer yet.
       event.response.issueTokens = false;
       event.response.failAuthentication = false;
       event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
   }
   
   return event;
};
```

create challenge

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: "eu-west-2" });

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
   var verificationCode = 0;
  
       const n = crypto.randomInt(0, 100000);
       verificationCode = n.toString().padStart(6, "0");
       
       const minimumNumber = 0;
       const maximumNumber = 100000;
        
       verificationCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximumNumber) + minimumNumber;
       console.log('send email');
       console.log('verificationCode: '+ verificationCode);
       console.log('email: '+ event.request.userAttributes.email);

       const params = {
           Destination: { ToAddresses: [event.request.userAttributes.email] },
           Message: {
               Body: {
                   Html: {
                       Charset: 'UTF-8',
                       Data: `<html><body><p>This is your secret login code:</p>
                           <h3>${verificationCode}</h3></body></html>`
                   },
                   Text: {
                       Charset: 'UTF-8',
                       Data: `Your secret login code: ${verificationCode}`
                   }
               },
               Subject: {
                   Charset: 'UTF-8',
                   Data: 'Your secret login code'
               }
           },
           Source: 'my email'
       };
       await ses.sendEmail(params).promise().then((res) => {
           console.log(res);
       });

   //add to privateChallengeParameters, so verify auth lambda can read this. this is not sent to client.
   event.response.privateChallengeParameters = { "verificationCode": verificationCode };
   //add it to session, so its available during the next invocation.
   event.response.challengeMetadata = verificationCode;
   
   return event;
   };
```